# Downcasting Rc<A> to Rc<B> if A == B

Tags: rust, unsafe

I would like to know if the following code is a valid use (maybe there is a builtin/safe way to downcast `Rc<dyn SomeTrait>` to `Rc<SomeType>`? I couldn't find any) and most importantly, is it safe?

```rust
use std::any::*;
use std::rc::*;

// NOTE: apparently adding Any here is REQUIRED
//       otherwise it doesn't work at all,
//       I have no idea why
trait SomeTrait: Any {}
struct SomeType;

impl SomeTrait for SomeType {}

fn rc_downcaster<A: 'static, B: ?Sized + 'static>(b: Rc<B>) -> Option<Rc<A>> {
    if Any::type_id(&*b) == TypeId::of::<A>() {
        Some(unsafe {
            let p = Rc::into_raw(b);
            Rc::from_raw(p as *const A)
        })
    } else {
        None
    }
}


fn main() {
    let x: Rc<dyn SomeTrait> = Rc::new(SomeType);
    let _: Rc<SomeType> = rc_downcaster(x).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8044f32a16b9c8e64347b3598d37cf8)

Comment: You can [use `Rc::downcast` if you are on nightly and add `#![feature(trait_upcasting)]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8044f32a16b9c8e64347b3598d37cf8). Since that works your code should be sound as well.

Comment: Hah, copied the wrong link, here is [a link to the actual thing I wanted to showcase](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f506c2d3768a1a150fb8c0174cdd14b9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using nightly, I found this safe alternative solution:

```
use std::any::*;
use std::rc::*;

trait SomeTrait: AsAny {}
struct SomeType;

impl SomeTrait for SomeType {}

trait AsAny {
    fn as_any(self: Rc<Self>) -> Rc<dyn Any>;
}

impl<T: 'static> AsAny for T {
    fn as_any(self: Rc<Self>) -> Rc<dyn Any> where Self: Sized
    {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: Rc<dyn SomeTrait> = Rc::new(SomeType);
    let x: Rc<dyn Any> = x.as_any();
    let _: Rc<SomeType> = Rc::downcast(x).unwrap();
}
```

But it is worth mentioning the solution of @cafce25 (in comment):

> You can use Rc::downcast if you are on nightly and add #![feature(trait_upcasting)]. Since that works your code should be sound as well. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f506c2d3768a1a150fb8c0174cdd14b9)

Comment: I wracked my brain a few times and I can't come up with a simpler answer on stable. You could define `AsAny` in slightly different ways -- avoiding hardcoding `Rc` would be nice -- but you'd still need some variant of it. And you need `AsAny` as super-trait because you can't have `dyn A + B` unless one of A or B is an auto-trait.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why is `Any` necessary?

Rust subscribes to a philosophy of explicit behavior.

This can be seen in a number of decisions -- such as nominal typing instead of structural typing -- and is reflected in the explicitness of function signatures. In particular, with generics, the set of possible operations on the generic type is encoded in the list of *traits* required for this generic type.

Unprincipled downcasting, that is the ability to always go back from super type to sub type, breaks that. A practical consequence is that it breaks wrapper types, for example, since now a function generic over `T` can have a different behavior based on whether I pass a `String` or a `struct Wrapper(String)` even if all the traits this function declares are implemented in the same way for both.

Therefore, Rust bans unprincipled downcasting *in general* and instead provides *one* escape hatch: `Any`. `Any` is a signal to the user that downcasting *may* be used, and therefore that the *exact* type may matter.

#### How to downcast, thus?

Well, by using `Any`!

```rust
#![feature(trait_upcasting)]

use std::{any::Any, rc::Rc};

struct SomeType;

trait SomeTrait: Any {}

impl SomeTrait for SomeType {}

fn main() {
    let x: Rc<dyn SomeTrait> = Rc::new(SomeType);

    let x: Rc<dyn Any> = x; // trait_upcasting necessary here.

    let _: Rc<SomeType> = Rc::downcast(x).unwrap();
}
```

All `'static` types implement `Any`.

#### Why `'static`?

Lifetimes are pure compile-time constructs, and are thus not tracked by `Any`, so allowing any lifetime would lead to soundness holes. Restricting to only `'static` was thus a conservative "known-sound" choice.

It's possible that an `Any<'a>` trait could be developed in the future; it gets tricky enough with lifetime variance (and covariance) that I couldn't say either way.

Comment: @interjay: Not without trait upcasting, at least. I was trying to clean-up the OP's answer, and I realize now they dropped the trait...

Comment: oh no I just forgot to put it back